# django-filer raises django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: filer_file

Tags: django, django-admin, migration, django-filer

I am trying to implement [django-filer](https://django-filer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) into my models in Django Admin for extended file upload functionality. No matter how many times I have dropped my database and re-run migrations, I am getting a `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: filer_file` error when I migrate the database.

I've read every post related to this on StackOverflow and none of them have helped me. I've tried faking migrations too and it starts to delete stale files, but then I get this error anyway.

When I try to access the model via Django Admin, I get

```
OperationalError: no such column: attorneydoc.attachment_id
```

Here is my models.py:

```
class AttorneyDoc(models.Model):
    attachment = FilerFileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And here is admin.py:

```
@admin.register(AttorneyDoc)
class AttorneyDocAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     ...
```

What do I need to do in order to resolve this?

Comment: Did you run migrations?

Comment: @AntoinePinsard Yes, many times. Still getting the error.

Comment: Please show full stack trace so we can figure out where the error comes from.